# Monitor CPU spikes of any process over X percent for Y seconds

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, cpu, performancecounter

I would like to run a .NET console application on our Windows Server 2008 box, which monitors CPU usage every 2 seconds.

If any single application uses > 30% CPU, two times in a row, it should be logged.

I will execute "CheckCpu" every 2 seconds... but my problem is, **how do I determine the CPU usage of each process?  And, efficiently** so that I don't bog down our server :)

```
Dim lStrProcessCurrent As List(Of String)
Dim lStrProcessPrevious As List(Of String)

Private Sub CheckCpu()

    Dim pcc As New PerformanceCounterCategory("Process")

    'Clear "Current" run
    lStrProcessCurrent = New List(Of String)

    For Each instance As String In pcc.GetInstanceNames
        Using cnt As PerformanceCounter = New PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", instance, True)

            Dim processName As String = cnt.InstanceName

 ' ?????  HOW TO DETERMINE CPU USAGE   ????
            Dim cpuUsage As Long = 31

            If cpuUsage >= 30 Then

                'Was over 30% in Previous check
                If lStrProcessPrevious.Contains(processName) Then
                    LogCpuSpike(processName)
                End If

                lStrProcessCurrent.Add(processName)
            End If

        End Using
    Next

    'Update "Previous" run
    lStrProcessPrevious = lStrProcessCurrent

End Sub
```

Comment: Question got downvoted but no comment.  Was my question unclear?  Did I not put fourth development effort?

Comment: Pretty sure the Windows Resource Monitor can do that without your having to write any code at all.

Comment: I consider it a good question. Some people immediately downvote a question they don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the code below. Effectively, check the TotalProcessorTime for each process each time you call CheckCpu() and then subtract this from the previous run and divide by the total time that has elapsed between the two checks.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim previousCheckTime As New DateTime
    Dim previousProcessList As New List(Of ProcessInformation)

    ' Kick off an initial check
    previousCheckTime = Now
    previousProcessList = CheckCPU(previousProcessList, Nothing)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        previousProcessList = CheckCPU(previousProcessList, Now - previousCheckTime)
        previousCheckTime = Now

        For Each process As ProcessInformation In previousProcessList
            Console.WriteLine(process.Id & " - " & Math.Round(process.CpuUsage, 2).ToString & "%")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("-- Next check --")
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function CheckCPU(previousProcessList As List(Of ProcessInformation), timeSinceLastCheck As TimeSpan) As List(Of ProcessInformation)

    Dim currentProcessList As New List(Of ProcessInformation)
    For Each process As Process In Process.GetProcesses()

        ' Id = 0 is the system idle process so we don't check that
        If process.Id <> 0 Then

            ' See if this process existed last time we checked
            Dim cpuUsage As Double = -1
            Dim previousProcess As ProcessInformation = previousProcessList.SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.Id = process.Id)

            ' If it did then we can calculate the % of CPU time it has consumed
            If previousProcess IsNot Nothing AndAlso timeSinceLastCheck <> Nothing Then
                cpuUsage = ((process.TotalProcessorTime - previousProcess.TotalProcessorTime).Ticks / (Environment.ProcessorCount * timeSinceLastCheck.Ticks)) * 100
            End If

            ' Add to the current process list
            currentProcessList.Add(New ProcessInformation With {.Id = process.Id, .CpuUsage = cpuUsage, .TotalProcessorTime = process.TotalProcessorTime})
        End If

    Next

    Return currentProcessList

End Function

Class ProcessInformation
    Public Id As Integer
    Public TotalProcessorTime As TimeSpan
    Public CpuUsage As Double
End Class
```

In a production environment you should probably add some more checks because it is possible for a process to be killed between you calling GetProcesses() and then processing the list. If the process has gone away then you will get an error when you try to access the TotalProcessorTime property.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this code.  Thank you very much for the help!  . . . . (CurrCPU - PreviousCPU) / (CurrTime - PreviousTime) * 100